# MSWord - ActiveX Fails to Invoke Objects

Tags: vba, matlab, ms-word, activex

After a year using the *MS Word 2013 VBA* through *ActiveX* server calls under *MS Win 8 Pro x64*, the following call ends in error:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields
```

Yesterday I made a *Windows Update* including a *Security Update for MSOffice 2013 64-bit*. Today I uninstalled the update, and the problem now persists.

**1. Matlab 2014b**

```
X=actxserver('Word.Application');
XD=X.Documents.Open('file.docx');
XD.FormFields

    No appropriate method, property, or field FormField for class Interface.Microsoft_Word_15.0_Object_Library._Document.
```

Most simple direct calls into the *ActiveX* server properties still work well:

```
XD=X.Documents.Add;
XS=X.Selection;
XS.Font.Name='Courier New';
XS.Pagesetup.RightMargin=28.34646;
... etc
```

But any call for invoking a `Document` object (through `.Documents.Add`, `.ActiveDocument`, `.Documents.Item(1)`, etc.) fails; listing their fields or methods shows nothing. Hence the subsequent calls to the `Document` object deliver no results:

```
XD=X.Documents.Add;
    XD = Interface.Microsoft_Word_15.0_Object_Library._Document
get(XD)
    struct with no fields.
invoke(XD)       
    <Nothing>
```

I also did not found any reference in Matlab Documentation to this behavior.

**2. MS Word**

Calls made directly inside Visual Basic Editor works fine:

```
MsgBox ActiveDocument.FormFields.Count

    0
```

I was searching in the *VBA* *Object Browser*, but it still lists the `Document` object including an instance of the `FormFields` class. But the error suggest the `_Document` class do not, which is not listed in the "Object Browser" when i seek by using that underscored name.

Is there any reference on why the calls to these objects fail, while the standard simpler properties still works through the *ActiveX* calls?

Comment: you can try re-compiling the project (Debug > Compile Project), or copy the macro to a new document and try from there.

Comment: It may well be a problem (bug) with the update. Try rolling it back and see whether the problem goes away. Then apply it again and see if the problem comes back. Is this really VBA by the way? I've never seen a reference to _Document in VBA, only in .NET languages...

Comment: FWIW I just forced a Windows 10 64-bit update, then tested Word->Excel and Excel->Word and have no difficulties. I've never used MatLab, but actxserver would be "ActiveX Server" which is also known as OLE Server. An OLE Server is an application that exposes a programming interface and is registered in the Windows Registry as such. If you search "Word.Application" for example, you should turn up any number of "hits".

Comment: Things to try: 1) REPAIR the Office installation. - If the update messed up something in the Registry, this could fix it. Or try uninstall/reinstall. 2) start a new project (for testing purposes). Create a new reference to the Word library (we'd have to do that in VBA, don't know what your equivalent is) and try accessing the Document object, again.

Comment: I did a repair, restarted the Trust Setting Option, and then restarted the system. That works, fortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Repairing the installation
2. The option *File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Developer Macro Settings>Trust access to the VBA project object model* is Checked, which I suppose enable the VBA calls from ActiveX Servers (That is a guess).
3. Restart the System.